# Return template iterator based on argument class

Tags: c++, templates, c++11, iterator, sfinae

I'm writing an algorithm function that uses iterators. This function should work with both normal and constant iterators, and importantly the class that these iterators come from is NOT a template, I know it in advance.

Is there any way to enforce in the following definition that the iterators come from a specific class?

```
// This is an example, A could be any other class with exposed iterators.
using A = std::vector<int>;

// How to enforce that Iterator is an iterator from A?
template <typename Iterator>
Iterator foo(Iterator begin, Iterator end);

...

A a;
auto it = foo(a.begin(), a.end());
*it = 4; // Must compile

// --------

const A a;
auto it = foo(a.begin(), a.end());
*it = 4; // Must not compile

// --------

B b;
auto it = foo(b.begin(), b.end()); // Should not compile.
```

In this case, `foo` does not modify directly the supplied range, but allows for modification of the result iterator if the supplied range was modifiable in the first place. It would be nice if this could be done without replicating code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might use std::enable_if:

```
#include <type_traits>
#include <vector>

class X : public std::vector<int> {};
class Y : public std::vector<double> {};

template <typename Iterator>
typename std::enable_if<std::is_same<Iterator, X::iterator>()
    || std::is_same<Iterator, X::const_iterator>(),
    Iterator>::type
foo(Iterator begin, Iterator end) {
    return begin;
}

int main() {
    X x0;
    auto i0 = foo(x0.begin(), x0.end());
    *i0 = 4; // Must compile

    const X x1;
    auto i1 = foo(x1.begin(), x1.end());
    // error: assignment of read-only location
    //*i1 = 4; // Must not compile

    Y y;
    // error: no type named ‘type’ in ‘struct std::enable_if ...
    //auto i2 = foo(y.begin(), y.end()); // Should not compile
}
```

Or static_assert as a nicer alternative:

```
template <typename Iterator>
Iterator foo(Iterator begin, Iterator end) {
    static_assert(std::is_same<Iterator, X::iterator>()
        || std::is_same<Iterator, X::const_iterator>(),
        "No X::iteator or X::const_iterator");
    return begin;
}
```

Answer (score 6):

Simply don't use template:

```
A::iterator foo(A::iterator begin, A::iterator end);
```

Comment: But won't this mean that I have to duplicate the function to make it work with both `iterator`s and `const_iterator`s? In the sense that I will have to duplicate the code?

Comment: @Svalorzen: I don't see how the same function would work on both const and non-const iterators.  Either the function is modifying things, or it's not.

Comment: @DanKorn Suppose I have a non-const object, and I want to pass two iterators to a non-modifying function. Then I want to take the resulting iterator, and use it to modify the object. The resulting iterator must be non-const if the two input ones are non-const.

Comment: Your statement "The resulting iterator must be non-const if the two input ones are non-const" is not necessarily true.  But it's not obvious from your description how your two hypothetical functions interact.  At any rate, both of the functions could just take and return const iterators, and then if someone wants to modify the result, it can be copied.

Answer (score 1):

You could use a function overload check:

```
inline void check_must_be_iterator_from_A(A::iterator) {}
inline void check_must_be_iterator_from_A(A::const_iterator) {}

template <typename I>
I foo(I a, I b) {
   typedef void (*must_be_iterator_from_A)(I);
   must_be_iterator_from_A c = &check_must_be_iterator_from_A;
   //...
}
```

The other option is to use template specialization to create a constraint, which makes the code within the function terser and definitely without runtime penalty regardless of compiler:

```
template <typename I> struct is_iterator_from_A;
template <> struct is_iterator_from_A<A::iterator>{ enum {ok}; };
template <> struct is_iterator_from_A<A::const_iterator>{ enum {ok}; };

template <typename I>
I bar(I a, I b) {
    is_iterator_from_A<I>::ok;
    return a;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I would first write your function for const iterators and then write a wrapper around it for the non_const case:

```
A::const_iterator foo(A::const_iterator start, A::const_iterator end)  {
    std::cout << " Called foo with const iterators " << std::endl;
    return start;
}

A::iterator foo(A::iterator start, A::iterator end) {
    std::cout << " Called foo with non_const iterators " << std::endl;  
    auto it = foo(static_cast<A::const_iterator>(start), static_cast<A::const_iterator>(end));
    return start + std::distance(static_cast<A::const_iterator>(start), it);
}
```

If you inline the wrapper function you should get zero (or nearly zero) overhead.

EDIT: 
In case your container doesn't provide random access iterators `distance` has linear complexity and you will have to use `std::advance` instead of the "+"-operator, so depending on your performance requirements this might not be a viable solution for you.